# Create a Pandas dataframe with counts of items spanning a date range

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DF that has two dates of interest that looks kind of like:

```
LIST_DATE     END_DATE
2000-04-18    2000-05-17 00:00:00
2000-05-18    2000-09-18 00:00:00
2000-04-18    2001-06-07 00:00:00
```

And I created a Period index table "montot" by month that currently only has the month and year index

```
<class 'pandas.tseries.period.PeriodIndex'>
freq: M
[1999-01, ..., 2013-07]
```

What I want to do is to for each month in the second table "montot" count the items in the 1st table which fall within the time periods (happens to be active listings by month) and add that field to the table... so for instance the 1st item in the 1st table would be counted 1 in month 4 and once in month 5 while the second item woul be counted once in month 5 through month 9 etc..with the monthly total being recorded in the new table/field.
So I'll have a table

```
Month    active
1/1999     5
2/1999     8
```

etc.. Have not got a clue how to approach it with Pandas/Python...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one way to do it, first [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) the *periods* in each of the date columns (using the `to_period` Timestamp method):

```
In [11]: p = pd.PeriodIndex(freq='m', start='2000-1', periods=18)

In [12]: starts = df['LIST_DATE'].apply(lambda t: t.to_period(freq='m')).value_counts()

In [13]: ends = df['END_DATE'].apply(lambda t: t.to_period(freq='m')).value_counts()
```

Reindex these by the PeriodIndex, fill in the NaNs (so you can subtract) and take the cumulative started from the cumulative ended, to give you the currently active:

```
In [14]: starts.reindex(p).fillna(0).cumsum() - ends.reindex(p).fillna(0).cumsum()
Out[14]: 
2000-01    0
2000-02    0
2000-03    0
2000-04    2
2000-05    2
2000-06    2
2000-07    2
2000-08    2
2000-09    1
2000-10    1
2000-11    1
2000-12    1
2001-01    1
2001-02    1
2001-03    1
2001-04    1
2001-05    1
2001-06    0
Freq: M, dtype: float64
```

An alternative final step is to create a DataFrame (which initially tracks changes, hence starts is positive and ends negative):

```
In [21]: current = pd.DataFrame({'starts': starts, 'ends': -ends}, p)

In [22]: current
Out[22]:
         ends  starts
2000-01   NaN     NaN
2000-02   NaN     NaN
2000-03   NaN     NaN
2000-04   NaN       2
2000-05    -1       1
2000-06   NaN     NaN
2000-07   NaN     NaN
2000-08   NaN     NaN
2000-09    -1     NaN
2000-10   NaN     NaN
2000-11   NaN     NaN
2000-12   NaN     NaN
2001-01   NaN     NaN
2001-02   NaN     NaN
2001-03   NaN     NaN
2001-04   NaN     NaN
2001-05   NaN     NaN
2001-06    -1     NaN

In [23]: current.fillna(0)
Out[23]:
         ends  starts
2000-01     0       0
2000-02     0       0
2000-03     0       0
2000-04     0       2
2000-05    -1       1
2000-06     0       0
2000-07     0       0
2000-08     0       0
2000-09    -1       0
2000-10     0       0
2000-11     0       0
2000-12     0       0
2001-01     0       0
2001-02     0       0
2001-03     0       0
2001-04     0       0
2001-05     0       0
2001-06    -1       0
```

The cumsum track the running totals of starts and ends up to that point:

```
In [24]: current.fillna(0).cumsum()
Out[24]:
         ends  starts
2000-01     0       0
2000-02     0       0
2000-03     0       0
2000-04     0       2
2000-05    -1       3
2000-06    -1       3
2000-07    -1       3
2000-08    -1       3
2000-09    -2       3
2000-10    -2       3
2000-11    -2       3
2000-12    -2       3
2001-01    -2       3
2001-02    -2       3
2001-03    -2       3
2001-04    -2       3
2001-05    -2       3
2001-06    -3       3
```

And summing these columns together, gives those currently active, and is same result as above:

```
In [25]: current.fillna(0).cumsum().sum(1)
```

Comment: Note: It's plausible you might want to .shift() the end dates here (before you fillna)...

Comment: This will take me a bit to absorb,,, hopefully I can try and verify tomorrow, thanks as always for the quick answer..

Comment: @dartdog it is rather involved, sorry about that! If you look at  each bit of the chain(s) it should make more sense (I thought my answer could get pretty long if I did that, but maybe I should've). Note: this answer assumes that your date columns are Timestamps.

Comment: @dartdog also, this question is "similar"... but a different approach. http://stackoverflow.com/q/18679586/1240268

Comment: It seems cool, and an approach I had not concieved of. They are all time stamps, I'm just slow on the uptake,, need to think about it, I'm sure you are right I just need to catch up! And apply the code,

Comment: @AndyHayden thanks for thge extra pointer looks helpful also, head explodes :-)

Comment: @dartdog I've broken it down a little, hopefully your head will un-explode by tomorrow. :)

Comment: Well I'm finally getting to it and sine my start_date is the DF index I'm stuck how to do the appy on the index This ain't it! starts = H2[H2.index].apply(lambda t: t.to_period(freq='m')).value_counts() H2.index is a no go as well..

Comment: You could reset_index. Also, perhaps use a df.index.map, rather than apply. ?

Comment: This fixed the lambda on the index and it all works great now! Thanks for all the help.. starts = H2.index.to_series().map (lambda t: t.to_period(freq='m')).value_counts()