# Pandas, simple add one month to a datetime column in a dataframe

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

As sort of a follow-up question to being able to count activity between two datetimes, ansered very well here: [Create a Pandas dataframe with counts of items spanning a date range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18775052/create-a-pandas-dataframe-with-counts-of-items-spanning-a-date-range/18775489#18775489)

The remaining issue is that the final month, ['END_DATE'] ends up showing zero after the two tables are summed and subtracted, which is mathematically correct since all items have an end date in that current month or earlier, however in this case since they have been active in that month at least for some portion, it would be more correct to add one month to END_DATE so they will show as active in the ending month (H2 is a dataframe)

The code is:

```
ends = H2['END_DATE'].apply(lambda t: t.to_period(freq='m')).value_counts()
```

I have tried to use rollforward and DateOffset(month=1) eg. for DateOffset:

```
ends = (H2['END_DATE'].DateOffset(months=1)).apply(lambda t: t.to_period(freq='m')).value_counts()
```

which gives me this error:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'DateOffset'
```

Comment: Are you trying to shift ends by one (month)?

Comment: yes I am, so that the ending month will be one greater than now that way the "last" month will be counted and not end up as zeroed out..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is to add one (month) to the PeriodIndex:

```
In [21]: ends
Out[21]:
2000-05    1
2000-09    1
2001-06    1
Freq: M, dtype: int64

In [22]: ends.index = ends.index + 1

In [23]: ends
Out[23]:
2000-06    1
2000-10    1
2001-07    1
Freq: M, dtype: int64
```

*My initial suggestion was to do the shift after you've reindexed (since you're about to do that anyway):*

```
In [11]: ends
Out[11]:
2000-05    1
2000-09    1
2001-06    1
Freq: M, dtype: int64

In [12]: p = pd.PeriodIndex(freq='m', start='2000-1', periods=19)  # Note: needs to be one more than before

In [13]: sparse_ends = ends.reindex(p)

In [14]: sparse_ends.shift(1)
Out[14]:
2000-01   NaN
2000-02   NaN
2000-03   NaN
2000-04   NaN
2000-05   NaN
2000-06     1
2000-07   NaN
2000-08   NaN
2000-09   NaN
2000-10     1
2000-11   NaN
2000-12   NaN
2001-01   NaN
2001-02   NaN
2001-03   NaN
2001-04   NaN
2001-05   NaN
2001-06   NaN
2001-07     1
Freq: M, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks, That will probably work, but is there not a simple way to just add a month to ['END_DATE'] ?

Comment: the shift index looks like a better fix, still would like to know if there is a simple date add function, which is how I'd do it in sql,  that could apply?

Comment: I see that, and I like it.. I'd still like to know if there is a simple DateAdd type function that I could use that might also apply for use elsewhere if needed?

Comment: @dartdog ah, to add to Series which have dates as the values? (I don't think so, is for DatetimeIndex, should add same for series)

Comment: Guess that is why I could not find it (seems like a strange omission, I was thinking it might be in some base (non Pandas) function?), but your solution work great, Thanks again

Comment: @dartdog agreed, I think there is an issue to add these helper functions to DatetimeIndex (atm sometimes converting to DatetimeIndex and applying is the fastest approach which seems silly!). I guess more "usual" to have time-indexed data, but I would like this!

Comment: To clarify myself, the issue is to make the datetime helpers (from DatetimeIndex) available to Series (with datetime values).

Comment: What then is DateOffset good for?? Seems like this situation?