# Sum of days in intervals

Tags: python, pandas, intervals

I have a pandas data frame as follows:

```
ID      Start        End
1  2013-03-03 2013-04-05
2  2013-03-03 2013-04-05
3  2012-03-02 2012-05-05
4  2013-03-01 2013-04-04
5  2013-02-25 2013-06-05
6  2012-02-26 2012-05-05
7  2013-02-25 2013-04-27
8  2012-02-26 2012-03-01
9  2013-03-22 2013-03-25
10 2013-06-27 2013-07-01
```

Is there a way to aggregate the number of days that occured per month:Year for each interval for each ID.

The output I am trying to get to is the sum of all the days per month:Year that each ID contributes.

So, ID1 will contrinute 29 days to March 2013 and 5 days to April 2013; ID3 will contribute 30days to March 2012, 30 days to April 2012, and 5 days to May 2012.
Etc....

Thanks in advance if you can help.

Comment: There is totally already a previous pandas question on this, will see if I can dig it up. Ah yes, this one: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18775052/1240268

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an awful way to do it:

```
In [11]: df1.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(1, pd.date_range(x.loc['Start'], x.loc['End'] - pd.offsets.Day(1), freq='D')).resample('M', how='sum'), axis=1).fillna(0)
Out[11]: 
    2012-02-29  2012-03-31  2012-04-30  2012-05-31  2013-02-28  2013-03-31  2013-04-30  2013-05-31  2013-06-30
ID                                                                                                            
1            0           0           0           0           0          29           4           0           0
2            0           0           0           0           0          29           4           0           0
3            0          30          30           4           0           0           0           0           0
4            0           0           0           0           0          31           3           0           0
5            0           0           0           0           4          31          30          31           4
6            4          31          30           4           0           0           0           0           0
7            0           0           0           0           4          31          26           0           0
8            4           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
9            0           0           0           0           0           3           0           0           0
10           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           4
```

To break it down, for each row we are calculating the days in each month by creating a Series of 1s for every day between the start and end, then summing them up for each month using resample:

```
In [12]: x = df1.iloc[0]

In [13]: x
Out[13]: 
Start   2013-03-03 00:00:00
End     2013-04-05 00:00:00
Name: 1, dtype: datetime64[ns]


In [14]: pd.Series(1, pd.date_range(x['Start'], x['End'] - pd.offsets.Day(1), freq='D')).resample('M', how='sum')
Out[14]: 
2013-03-31    29
2013-04-30     4
Freq: M, dtype: int64
```

Comment: I don't think this one is awful. Another way could be calculate all ends of the months between two dates, split period into several periods and then calculate difference between those dates, anyway here my +1

Comment: @andy-hayden - think is pretty much what I was after. The format looks suitable for the data I have to report.

Answer (score 1):

The *datetime* module has the tools you need to do month by month manipulation of dates.

Here's some quick stand-alone code that can easily be adapted to a *Pandas* dataframe:

```
import datetime
import collections
import pprint

data = '''\
1  2013-03-03 2013-04-05
2  2013-03-03 2013-04-05
3  2012-03-02 2012-05-05
4  2013-03-01 2013-04-04
5  2013-02-25 2013-06-05
6  2012-02-26 2012-05-05
7  2013-02-25 2013-04-27
8  2012-02-26 2012-03-01
9  2013-03-22 2013-03-25
10 2013-06-27 2013-07-01
'''

for line in data.splitlines():
    idnum, startstr, endstr = line.split()
    start = datetime.datetime.strptime(startstr, '%Y-%m-%d')
    end = datetime.datetime.strptime(endstr, '%Y-%m-%d')

    days_in_month = collections.Counter()
    current = start
    while current <= end:
        days_in_month[current.year, current.month] += 1
        current += datetime.timedelta(1)
    print('Id: %s' % idnum)
    pprint.pprint(dict(days_in_month))
    print('-' * 10)
```